# Cassandra - Run multiple clusters on the same set of servers

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

I'm new to Cassandra. I have 6 physical servers with a 2 data center Cassandra cluster running.

Cass_cluster_1

Server 1  DC1: rac1
Server 2  DC1: rac1
Server 3  DC1: rac1

Server 4  DC2: rac1
Server 5  DC2: rac1
Server 6  DC2: rac1

Can I use the same servers and run another Cassandra Cluster with different keyspace and tables? Do I need a separate Cassandra install? Would I use different ports for listen address, etc? Is this even feasable?

Want to create Cass_cluster_2

Server 1  DC1: rac1
Server 2  DC1: rac1
Server 3  DC1: rac1

Server 4  DC2: rac1
Server 5  DC2: rac1
Server 6  DC2: rac1

Comment: This grew out of managements desire to save money in the development environment. I have since told them it is not possible. Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run two Cassandra instances on the same server. Each Cassandra service uses fixed ports and no two instances can share a port.

The best way to load up multiple Cassandra instances on same server is to boot up multiple virtual machines and install Cassandra separately on each.

Comment: It's possible but whether is desirable performance wise is another thing. We run two 2.1 cluster instances across same set of nodes in production. One cluster with data on ssd another on spindles, commitlogs on a shared ssd mirror. But it all depends and milage varies for everyone. Remember to change cassandra-env.sh, all ports should be unique and use unique config directory and test. In general share at a minimum level (cpu, memory, data dirs/spindles, NICs etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this https://github.com/pcmanus/ccm. If saving cost is the major concern why don't you reduce the existing cluster to 1 data center and use other 3 nodes for new cluster